# RAID0 Thunderbolt Drive failure risk

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid, storage, thunderbolt

I'm thinking of purchasing a Thunderbolt drive to both work off of and also do some long term storage on. (The WD Velociraptor Duo, specifically.)

My problem though, is that the majority of 'speedy' Thunderbolt drives are RAID0 and I've always been paranoid about running anything in RAID0.

Switching to RAID1 sounds okay, but it means working off of it wouldn't be all that fast. Am I right to be so paranoid about having a RAID0 external containing my work, old photos, etc?

I'd certainly backup the important files, but I can't shake the feeling that an external RAID0 Thunderbolt setup seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using any RAID with removable media on USB, eSATA, Thunderbolt, etc, sounds like asking for trouble.

Imagine what will happen if one of your RAIDed drives happens to be disconnected because you (or your dog) accidentally pulled thunderbolt or USB cable?

Because of these issues, RAID drives are better off mounted in bays, cages or in NAS boxes and left alone.

Comment: The two drives aren't separate- the external I mentioned (the WD Velociraptor Duo) is an external with two bays connected to a computer via Thunderbolt.

Comment: Ah, that's no so bad then. That said, I heard so many horror stories about WD NAS boxes, that I would rather stay away from them.